# Как задавать View в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Создал в проекте модуль(с базовым HelloWorld-Activity), хотел накидать на болванку кнопок и прочих элементов,но создался Custom View- ...CoordinatorLayout и на него нельзя перетащить элементы. Я так понял, что в нем и Scroll View может быть 1 элемент и больше добавить нельзя.Проблема решилась созданием нового проекта, в котором создался Relative Layout и можно было добавлять элементы. Вопрос-как указывать этот параметр и от чего зависит создание Layout'ов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Забудьте о существовании графического способа создания разметки. Чтобы в нём разобраться так, чтобы им можно было пользоваться в ситуациях сложнее, чем помещение текста по середине экрана вам надо стать крутым профессионалом в составлении разметки в `xml`
2. В CoordinatorLayout можно добавить много View. Не добавлялись они у вас из-за глюклв графического редактора, плохо справляющегося с виджетами новыми.

**Итого:**

Создавайте разметку только через `xml` и не пользуйтесь графическими средствами.

Comment: здравствуйте,большое спасибо за советы. я только осваиваю эту область,в уроке для тренировки было небольшое задание-поиграться с этим редактором, вот я и поковырялся,ну и решил узнать в чем проблема.значит небольшой глюк ide..
есть толковые источники по изучению xml?для новичка

Comment: @Iga, эти уроки быстро устаревают и зря они советуют графическим редактором пользоваться... Да, на первых попрах так может быть нагляднее, проще и быстрее, но, как я и говорил, там всё так плохо, что лучше его вообще не трогать. А уроки по xml разметке... Ну, всё те же самые, только без графического редактора)

Comment: не рекомендуют они.это был урок с ознакомлением интерфейса,для понимания что такое layout и т.д.(чтобы не бросать людей не сведущих в xml вроде меня под танк сразу))